# How to know the position and the size of a SVG path after having changed the stroke width?

Tags: javascript, svg

After changing with javascript the stroke-with of a path of a svg, the drawing exceeds the width and the height of the ViewBox.
But I want the path including its stroke to be fully visible in the ViewBox.

```js
var p2 = document.getElementById('p2');
p2.setAttribute("stroke-width", "20");
```

```html
<svg width="87.827858" height="75.68341" viewBox="0 0 87.827858 75.683411" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color: tomato" id="svg1">
  <path stroke="green" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="2.84261" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-dashoffset="150" id="p1"
     d="m 19.767551,1.421305 h 66.639003 c 0,24.787544 0,49.201764 0,72.571424 l -72.237524,0.26727 c -6.271839,-5.9713 -3.416511,-11.33672 -6.595083,-19.10577 -2.708216,-6.6194 6.437081,-17.92492 -3.523279,-17.25944 -10.108666,0.6754 12.178156,-25.397641 15.716883,-36.473484 z" />
</svg>

<svg width="87.827858" height="75.68341" viewBox="0 0 87.827858 75.683411" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color: tomato" id="svg2">
  <path stroke="green" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="2.84261" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-dashoffset="150" id="p2"
     d="m 19.767551,1.421305 h 66.639003 c 0,24.787544 0,49.201764 0,72.571424 l -72.237524,0.26727 c -6.271839,-5.9713 -3.416511,-11.33672 -6.595083,-19.10577 -2.708216,-6.6194 6.437081,-17.92492 -3.523279,-17.25944 -10.108666,0.6754 12.178156,-25.397641 15.716883,-36.473484 z" />
</svg>
```

How to know the size of the path including the stroke ? Then I could change the size of the ViewBox.

How to know the position (negative position, I guess) of the path including the stroke ? Then I could add the attribute transform (translate).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getBBox` to get the bounds of a path but it ignores the stroke witdth. Adding the stroke width to the resulting bounds can help to some extent as you can see in the snippet, but you cannot count on it.

The red square represents the original bounds and the blue one is an enlarged original one (stroke with added to the each side):

```js
const box = d3.select('path').node().getBBox();
console.log(box);

d3.select('svg')
    .append('rect')
  .attr('x', box.x)
  .attr('y', box.y)
  .attr('width', box.width)
  .attr('height', box.height)
  .style('stroke', 'red')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  
 d3.select('svg')
    .append('rect')
  .attr('x', box.x - 10)
  .attr('y', box.y - 10)
  .attr('width', box.width + 20)
  .attr('height', box.height + 20)
  .style('stroke', 'blue')
  .style('fill', 'none')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="250" height="200">
  <path d="M 100,50 L 190,180 Q 180,60 70,90 Z" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="10" />
  <path d="M 100,50 L 190,180 Q 180,60 70,90 Z" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael . Indeed, angles are a problem. In that case, the width of the stroke will exceed the stroke-width, which we can notice on your example.

Comment: You can use stroke-miterlimit to cap the extent of a spiky small-angle mitered line-join  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-miterlimit